# Yii captcha code is showing different codes in view and in controller

Tags: php, yii

In my `controller` is use

```
$captcha=Yii::app()->getController()->createAction("captcha");
$code = $captcha->verifyCode;
```

And in view i use

```
<?php $this->widget('CCaptcha'); ?>
```

but both `captcha` codes are different and hence I am unable to `compare` my captcha

Any help...